# Unable to run php script with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I installed nginx on my Lubuntu 13.04 32 bit using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
sudo apt-get install mercurial libpcre3-dev libssl-dev
hg clone -r stable-1.4 http://hg.nginx.org/nginx nginx
cd nginx
auto/configure --with-http_ssl_module 
make
sudo make install
```

After it I disabled apache:

```
sudo kill $(pidof apache2)
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

and I edited the nginx.conf, that now is:

```
worker_processes  1;

events
{
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http
{
    include            mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server
    {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        index        index.html index.php;

        location /
        {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.php;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$
        {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html
        {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

So I started nginx, I wrote a test.php script inside the html directory with only

```
<?php
    echo 'OK!';
```

and I opened it inside the browser, but it doesn't work. The error is:

> [error] 2886#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request:
>   "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:
>   "localhost"

php5-fpm seems to be already started, since if I try sudo php5-fpm, I get this error:

```
ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Comment: Does `netstat -lpn | grep php-fpm` show any output? What about iptables?

Comment: @NathanC: netstat returns `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13018    2168/php-fpm.conf)  /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`. I've no iptables rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP-FPM installation is set up to use sockets and not TCP.

Change this line:

`fastcgi_pass fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;`

To: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/php5-fpm.sock;`

Alternatively you can modify your nginx.conf file's `listen =` to use a port instead of the socket.

Comment: It works :) PS: despite of what php5-fpm and netstat say, my socket is in `/run/php5-fpm.sock` , and this is the reason: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57297/why-has-var-run-been-migrated-to-run